# What do the curly braces around variable name without assignment operator mean

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm learning how to use Redux and React and found a couple pieces of code in the Redux shopping cart example project:

In the actions/index.js module:

```
export const addToCart = productId => (dispatch, getState) => {
   if (getState().products.byId[productId].inventory > 0) {
    dispatch(addToCartUnsafe(productId))
  }
}
```

And in ProductContainer module:

```
import { addToCart } from '../actions'

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addToCart }
)(ProductsContainer)
```

I don't understand what the { addToCart } construct means. It looks a little like destructuring but without assinging operator. Can someone point me at what is it and when do we need to use such syntax?

Comment: Which of the two are you referring to?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the ambiguity, I meant the latter one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{ addToCart }` is shortHand for `{ addToCart: addToCart }`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, where can I read about it?

Comment: See "Property definitions" in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer